# SemaphoreSlim not spinning up to maximum number of threads

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, task, semaphore

I thought I understood the SemaphoreSlim, but I think I need some help.  If I declare a semaphore with a maxCount of 2, then I assumed the semaphore count would grow up to a maximum of 2 with every call to WaitAsync() within the loop allowing up to two task to run at a time, but it only runs one at a time even though I release the Semaphore at the end of each task.  Can someone shed some light as to why this code runs one task at a time?

```
class Program
{
    static SemaphoreSlim _loopThrottle = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 2);

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int taskID = 1; taskID <= 10; taskID++)
        {
            await _loopThrottle.WaitAsync();
            var t = SomeFunctionAsync(taskID);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async static Task SomeFunctionAsync(int taskID)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(taskID);
        _loopThrottle.Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the SemaphoreSlim constructor parameters, initialCount should be 2. You're claiming one of the two available "slots" is not available (your .CurrentCount will be 1 in the beginning). Because there's only one request remaining, your loop can't fire the SomeFunctionAsync() tasks at a greater rate than one at a time. Because each of these only Release() once, you're never freeing up the two slots you've declared as maxCount.

Comment: For this scenario, you can just use the single-parameter constructor ```new SemaphoreSlim(2)```

Comment: That's kind of what I'm seeing.  If the first value of the constructor always controls the maximum allowed threads, then why have the second one that actually specifies the max count? Still must be missing some thing simple.

Comment: With regard to claiming one of the available spots, I changed the params to be 1 and 5 and it still only processes one at a time.  static SemaphoreSlim _loopThrottle = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 5);

Comment: By specifying (1,5), you're claiming a maximum of five can be granted, but that only one is currently available, which is why you see this one-at-a-time behaviour. Each task is blocked by the previous one, which only release a single spot. Try it with (5,5) and it will work as expected.

Comment: Maybe I need to ask this differently then.  Declaring the semaphore with a single value of 5 appears to behave the same if I use the second constructor that takes two values (initial and max) (5,5).  There must be a reason why they have both constructors right?  Logically I see the reason for both.  "I may have up to 5 things happening but I may not so only use as many as you need up to that amount" which would be a 1, 5 set of params.  Or I am always going to have a 5 things running at a time so go ahead and predeclare them as 5, 5).

Comment: Oh yes, now I get you. With the 1-param constructor, you can call Release() as many times as you wish and it will increase the max amount of concurrent requests. With the 2-param constructor, calling Release() over the max will throw a SemaphoreFullException.